# Self-capacitance formula for planar inductors

Tags: capacitance, math, planar-inductor

I'm designing a Rectangular Planar Spiral inductor with a rectangular conductor cross-section (it's not made from cylindrical wire) for use in an RLC circuit (an NFC tag), and I can not optimise the antenna without knowing the parasitic capacitance of the transponder layout.

I imagine that this is the sum of the capacitance of the IC chip and the self-capacitance of the inductor.

I'm looking for a formula that will determine the self-capacitance of the inductor.

Bonus points if you can give me Octave code for it.

Comment: Mind, you need not just self-capacitance (an approximate figure!), but its self-resonant frequency, or whole impedance vs. frequency, so that it can be resonant in the final circuit, correct?  Will this be optimized to use no external components (IC self capacitance only) or are tuning capacitors allowed?

Comment: I'm currently optimising without the use of a tuning capacitor, but I may choose to use a tuning capacitor as the project advances @TimWilliams

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm able to estimate inductance to a reasonable accuracy and I can calculate the resonance frequency, although I'm optimising using the formula for Interrogation Field Strength.

Comment: Right now, I just need the parasitic capacitance of the transponder layout.

Comment: You will need external tuning capacitors and, probably ones that ought to be selected on test hence, there's no point trying to find the inductors SRF parasitic capacitance because the external capacitance should swamp it.